# Positioning images (icons) in treeview

Tags: css, image, positioning

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fGPAXVN.png]

I'm trying to position the - and + icons to the right of the treeline, but before the text "Mammals" and "Elephant"

http://cssdeck.com/labs/sd1cnqm7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need:

```
.treeView li.collapsibleListOpen {
    background: url('http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/button-open.png') no-repeat 1em 0.5em;
    list-style: none;
}
.treeView li.collapsibleListClosed {
    background: url('http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/button-closed.png') no-repeat 1em 0.5em;
    list-style: none;
}
.treeView li {
    padding: 0px 2em;
    /* rest of the styles */
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/suaLyrop/